# What tag libraries you know for Java EE JSP, something like displaytag?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tags

What tag libraries you know for Java EE - JSP, something like [displaytag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/) ?

Comment: Not only for display tables, all kind of useful thing...

Answer (score 5):

Looking for an alternative to displaytag I came across [jmesa](http://code.google.com/p/jmesa/). Haven't tried it yet, tough.

Answer (score 2):

JMesa is the successor of eXtremeTable.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative is [valuelist](http://valuelist.sourceforge.net/) - it's rather good implementation of Value List Handler Java EE pattern, but it's development seems to be stalled somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Also [ExtremeTable](http://code.google.com/p/extremetable/)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [jsp data grid](https://github.com/customweb/jsp-data-grid) library. It allows easy styling of all the elements (table, td, tr etc.). It is also integrated with Hibernate and Spring. It has also a AJAX mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Datatables](http://datatables.net/), which is jquery plugin. It is better than any other grid libraries.